# x-axis doesn't have any numbers, how to fix this?

Tags: r, boxplot

I making a boxplot, where I've named the x/y-axis something. The problem is that on the x-axis there is nothing besides the label I've made. I expected it that there would be 3, 5, 10 & 17 under the boxes.

[image]

I've used this command to make the boxplot:

```
boxplot(HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==3], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==5], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==10], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==17], 
        col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), 
        ylab ="Heat consumption (kW)", xlab="House")
```

Comment: Reproducible example (= some sample data)?

Comment: What do you need? The sample data the 4 houses? How do I upload them?

Comment: Try `boxplot(Q ~ houseId, data = HE.JF)`.

Comment: @Bob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Roland : That will make a boxplot of all the houses

Comment: Well, if you only want specific houses, it should be obvious to subset the data.frame: `boxplot(Q ~ houseId, data = HE.JF[HE.JF$houseId %in% c(3, 5, 10, 17),])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` does not print 3, 5, 10, 17 beneath the box plots, because it doesn't know the `houseID`.

This happens because you don't plot directly from `HE.JF$Q` (which you can do by use of a `formula`, as pointed out by @[Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) in a comment above). Instead what you do is to plot four individual extracts from `HE.JF$Q` (like `HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==3]`).

If this is how you want to do it, you can add the `names`-argument to `boxplot()`.

```
boxplot(HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==3], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==5], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==10], 
        HE.JF$Q[HE.JF$houseId==17], 
        col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), 
        ylab ="Heat consumption (kW)", xlab="House", 
        names = c("3","5","10","17"))
```

Comment: So if I want to make a boxplot with the 4 houses, I've to write `boxplot(?)`

Comment: I've updated the answer with your code to show you how to add the names argument.